# syntax error, unexpected keyword_end, expecting $end

Tags: ruby, syntax-error

i am just starting my journey with ruby and am very new to programming in general as well. This is code for a homework assignment. I am getting syntax error as described in title. I understand that I have added some extra end while end of file was expected? right?
but where is this extra "end".

The code:

```
class WrongNumberOfPlayersError < StandardError ; end
class NoSuchStrategyError < StandardError ; end

def rps_result(move1,move2)

  if (move1 == "r" && move2 == "s") || (move1 == "s" && move2 == p) || (move1 == "p" && move2 == "r")
    return true 
  else 
    return false
  end
```

end

```
  def rps_game_winner(player1, player2)    
    strategy = /[rps]/
    raise NoSuchStrategyError unless (move1 =~ strategy) & (move2 =~ strategy) 

    move1 = player1[1].downcase
    move2 = player2[2].downcase

    rps_result(move1, move2)? player1 : player2
  end
end

def rps_tournament_winner(game)
  round_winners = []

  if game.length < 2
    raise WrongNumberOfPlayersError
  else
    game.each_slice(2) do
      |l1 , l2|
      round_winners << rps_game_winner(l1, l2)
    end

    rps_tournament_winner(round_winners) 
  end
end

rps_tournament_winner([[[["Richard", "S"], ["Dave", "S"]], [["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"]]], [[["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"]], [["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"]]]])
```

Comment: In the future, please format your question for clarity (there is a view below the edit pane that shows how the question will actually be displayed)

Answer (score 0):

The `rps_result` method is never closed.  Move the second `end` at the end of `rps_game_winner` to the last intended line of the `rps_result` method.

P.s. sorry for all the `end`'s :)

Comment: Notice that you have two `end`'s at the end of your `rps_game_winner` method.  Try removing one.

Answer (score 0):

I have modified the second block of code. Please check if it works.

```
def rps_game_winner(player1, player2)    
    strategy = /[rps]/
    raise NoSuchStrategyError unless (move1 =~ strategy) && (move2 =~ strategy) 

    move1 = player1[1].downcase
    move2 = player2[2].downcase

    rps_result(move1, move2) ? player1 : player2
end    

def rps_tournament_winner(game)
  round_winners = []

  if game.length < 2
    raise WrongNumberOfPlayersError
  else
    game.each_slice(2) do |l1 , l2|
      round_winners << rps_game_winner(l1, l2)
    end

    rps_tournament_winner(round_winners) 
  end
end

rps_tournament_winner([[[["Richard", "S"], ["Dave", "S"]], [["Richard", "R"], ["Michael", "S"]]], [[["Allen", "S"], ["Omer", "P"]], [["David E.", "R"], ["Richard X.", "P"]]]])
```

Did 4 changes:

1. Removed extra `end` in `rps_game_winner` method.
2. Added space between tertiary operators in `rps_game_winner` method.
3. `rps_game_winner` method, 2nd line, `unless` condition had only one `&`.
4. In `rps_tournament_winner` method, moved the args `|l1, l2|` after `do`.

Comment: now i get this error:     in `rps_game_winner': undefined local variable or method `move1' for main:Object (NameError)
 from part2.rb:39:in `block in rps_tournament_winner'
 from part2.rb:37:in `each'
 from part2.rb:37:in `each_slice'
 from part2.rb:37:in `rps_tournament_winner'
 from part2.rb:48:in `<main>'

Comment: Is there an apostrophe(') after the method name `rps_game_winner` ?